# update table data using angularjs without using backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need a doubt in angularjs CRUD operation.. I almost completed but while updating my CRUD table, it shows some errors. I could not update my table instead of updating my table, it's adding a new row. I want to replace a value in same row itself.

```
$scope.deleteTable = function($index){
    //  var i =   $scope.users.indexOf(user);
    var myIndex = $index
    console.log(myIndex);
    var remove = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete!");
    if(remove == true){
        $scope.users.splice(myIndex,1)
    }
}

$scope.updateData = function(user){
    console.log("index",index);
    $scope.users.push(index);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your errors messages?

Answer (score 0):

The `updateData` function is pushing a new value to your `users` array resulting in a new row being added to your table. If you want to update the user, just update the property of the object passed in argument (so the `user` object). Something like this:

```
$scope.updateData = function(user){
    user.property = "value";
}
```

Besides, in your current function implementation, you're using an `index` variable that does not seem to exist. Maybe you should consider learning a bit more on AngularJS/JavaScript as the code you show seems to have multiple issues that could be fixed by knowing a bit more what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give the index as a parameter from html to $scope.updateData function then you could;

```
$scope.updateData = function(user, index){

  $scope.users[index] = user;

}
```

If you dont have the index information then you would have to loop in users to find which user to update as below

```
$scope.updateData = function(user){

  $scope.users.forEach(function(userToBeUpdated, i){
    if(user.id == userToBeUpdated.id){ //user object id property is assumed
      userToBeUpdated = user;
    }
  })
}
```